# What's the motivation for the $3$ appearing in Iwaniec and Kowalski's definition of the analytic conductor?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions

In their book Analytic Number Theory, Iwaniec and Kowalski, on page 95, define the analytic conductor by the following formula:

$\displaystyle{{\frak{q}}_{\infty}(s)=\prod_{j=1}^{d}\left(\vert s+\kappa_{j}\vert+3\right)}$

Where does this $+3$ come from? Is it related to the abscissa of convergence? If yes, how?

Comment: No, it's just there to ensure that $\log \mathfrak{q}_{\infty}(s) > 1$. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Thank you Peter but I guess you meant ${\frak{q}}_{\infty}(s)>1$ if I am to trust Carlo Beenakker's answer below?

Comment: Well, you must be right and Carlo wrong (or rather inaccurate) as we get something greater than $d\log e$.

Comment: If you just wanted $\mathfrak{q}_{\infty}(s) \geq 1$, then you could replace $3$ with $1$, which plenty of authors do. See also this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294208/consistency-of-the-notion-of-conductor-of-a-representation

Comment: Ok, thank you for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing special about the value "3", it is there to ensure that $\log{\frak{q}}_{\infty}(s)>0$ when $s\rightarrow\infty$.